# How to detect whether key Enter pressed, and then do specific function in Matlab GUI design?

Tags: matlab, keyboard

I want to check whether user is pressing key **Enter** when GUI is running, if yes, data will be stored. 
Here is some code:

```
if double(get(gcf,'CurrentCharacter'))==13
    tact=showData';    %'
    fid = fopen('tact.txt','at+');
    fprintf(fid,[repmat('%d ',1,size(tact,2)),'\n'],tact);
    fclose(fid);
end
```

Why does it appear another Figure. And it seems key state is not checked.
Thanks

Comment: It's a good practice to give tags to the figure windows of GUIs and use those in these scenarios. Thus, if you have a tag named `gui_figure`, use that instead of `gcf`. It could be one of the reasons, that's all.

Comment: The HandleVisibility property of your GUI is set such that the callback where you have this code is not seeing the handle.  Hence gcf is opening another figure rather than using the existing one.  As @Divakar suggests, give your GUI a unique tag and use findobj to search for the handle of the figure with that tag and use that handle instead of gcf.

Comment: I followed your instructions, change the tag of the figure and set HandleVisibility to be on. It works! Thanks both of you@Divakar@Phil Goddard!